# Q_PROPERTY NOT WORKING PROPERLY

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry, blackberry-10, qproperty

I am developing a bb10 app in cascades. 
Here is the snippet for the header file

```
//applicationui.hpp
Q_PROPERTY(int metric READ getMetric WRITE setMetric NOTIFY metricChanged)
public:
    int getMetric();
    void setMetric(int newMetric);

signals:
void metricChanged(int);
private:
    int m_metric;


//applicationui.cpp
ApplicationUI::ApplicationUI(bb::cascades::Application *app) :
    QObject(app)
{
    qml->setContextProperty("_app", this);
    // Set created root object as the application scene
    app->setScene(root);

    m_metric = 1;

}

int ApplicationUI::getMetric(){
    return m_metric;
}

void ApplicationUI::setMetric(int newMetric){
m_metric = newMetric;
emit metricChanged(m_metric);
}
```

In my main.qml I have a RadioGroup whose selectedIndex I would like to set depending on the metric value

```
RadioGroup {
                id: distanceMetric
                Option { id: option1; text: "Miles"}
                Option { id: option2; text: "Kilometers"}
                onCreationCompleted: {
                    distanceMetric.selectedIndex = _app.metric
                }
 }
```

But this doesnt seem to be working as expected.
Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanx

Comment: Why is not working as expected? Which results is giving to you and wich results do you expect?

Comment: What is the actual behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Does you class inherit QObject (I guess it must as it seems to be a widget)?

Did you include the Q_OBJECT macro?

Maybe the [doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/properties.html) could help if none of the above solve your issue? I'm not saying RTFM, just sometimes if you are using the website version of the docs, I find it a bit hard to find things.

Comment: You are giving wrong documentation to the OP. Blackberry 10 is not using Qt 5.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your QML scene is being created before you are setting the metric value to 1. Try changing this:

```
m_metric = 1;
```

to this:

```
setMetric(1);
```

so that the QML binding can be notified of the change.